# remove page from fixed document?

Tags: wpf, xps, fixeddocument

How can I remove a page from a fixedDocument?

I add pages like this:

```
// Add page to pageContent
PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();
((IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(fixedPage);

// Add pageContent to wholeDoc
fixedDocument.Pages.Add(pageContent);

//Add to documentVeiwer
documentViewer1.Document = fixedDocument;
```

But there is no 'fixedDocument.Pages.Remove(page)' method! What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try "cloning" the document into a new document and copy / move all pages over to the new document, except for the one(s) you want to remove?

Not sure if that would work or not.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but this came up for me recently.

```
public class MyFixedDocument : FixedDocument
{
    public FamilyLawFixedDocument() : base() { }

    public void RemoveChild(object child)
    {
        //call protected method of base class
        base.RemoveLogicalChild(child);
    }
}
```