# WPF - How do I remove page from FixedDocument?

Tags: c#, wpf, fixeddocument

I have a simple class called "MyPage":

```
public class MyPage
{
    public TextBlock tbParagraph;
    public FixedPage page;
    public PageContent content;

    public MyPage(string Text)
    {
        tbParagraph = new TextBlock();
        page = new FixedPage();
        content = new PageContent();

        tbParagraph.Text = Text;
        page.Children.Add(tbParagraph);
        content.Child = page;
    }
}
```

Now I can create a FixedDocument and add 3 pages with the content of "Page1", "Page2" and "Page3" respective to the order:

```
FixedDocument document = new FixedDocument();
public List<MyPage> listPages = new List<MyPage>();
listPages.Add(new MyPage("Page 1"));
listPages.Add(new MyPage("Page 2"));
listPages.Add(new MyPage("Page 3"));

foreach(MyPage pg in listPages)
{
    document.Pages.Add(pg.content);
}
```

Now is there a way to remove pages from FixedDocument? I know I can clear the specific page content with `document.Pages[2].Child.Children.Clear();` for example, but how do I remove a Page itself?

Comment: It doesn't look like it supports removal of a page out of the box.  [See previous question on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814992/remove-page-from-fixed-document)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.fixeddocument?view=netframework-4.8), FixedDocument is meant to be a display/print mechanism, and is not an interactive/editable.

That being said, you could achieve basic editing by allowing changes to the Text in your MyPage class and then re-building the FixedDocument as needed after the changes.

```
public class MyPage
{
    public TextBlock tbParagraph;
    public FixedPage page;
    public PageContent content;
    public string Text {get; set;}

    public MyPage(string myText)
    {
       Text = myText;
    }

    public PageContent GetPage()
    {
        tbParagraph = new TextBlock();
        page = new FixedPage();
        content = new PageContent();

        tbParagraph.Text = Text;
        page.Children.Add(tbParagraph);
        content.Child = page;
        return content;
    }
}
```